# Oracle SQL how should i write the following statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following logical statement:

```
[only if table2_column1= '1'] 
then:
  If
    table1_column='auto'
  Then
    If
      table2_column2='1'  
    Then
      If
        table2_column3='1' 
      Then
        RESULT A
      Else
       RESULT B
    Else
      If
        table2_column2='1'
    Then
      RESULT C
    Else
      RESULT D
  Else
    RESULT E
```

How can I express this in Oracle SQL? (case when else??)

Comment: I edited your question to show the nesting of `If/Then/Else`. Hopefully I got the indentation correct.

Comment: Yes, a `case when` ...

Comment: Replace the word `IF` with the word `CASE`. Then write an `END` where each `END IF` should be and you're done...

Comment: Look at the [DECODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions042.htm#SQLRF00631) syntax.

Comment: @Ben But does Oracle support nested `CASE`? If not, then each path needs to be expressed in a single case condition.

Comment: It does support nested case statements @Michael.

Comment: Don't use (or recommend) `DECODE()` @eebbesen... it is non-ANSI SQL, in certain situations it converts everything to a VARCHAR2, sometimes to random datatypes, it's less flexible and it can't be used in PL/SQL. There's really no reason to not use CASE.

Comment: thanks. Why using Decode? /-: i just stuck in how exactly i should write this statement (what is the full syntax)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `case` logic is best expressed something like this:

```
select (case when t2.column1 = '1' and t.column = 'auto' and t2.column2 = '1' and t2.column3 = '1'
     then A
         when t2.column1 = '1' and t.column = 'auto' and t2.column2 = '1' 
         then B
         when t2.column1 = '1' and t.column = 'auto'
         then D
         when t2.column1 = '1'
         then E
 end) as Result
```

**Note:**  There is no `C` because that condition is redundant with the condition for B.  I have assumed that `table_. . .` really means the column from `Table2`, rather than a strange column name from the table.

**Note:** that the `case` statement is processed sequentially, so the first match is the one returned.  This gives it the same power as a bunch of if/then/else statements, but often with a structure that some find to be simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's ur written code. Bit messy nests huh! I believe you just need a skeleton. Hope I helped you!
Two Possibilities using `DECODE` and `CASE WHEN`

```
 DECODE(table2_column1,
        '1',DECODE(table1_column,
                   'auto',DECODE(table2_column2,
                                 '1',DECODE(table2_column3,
                                            '1','A'
                                            'B'),
                                 DECODE(table2_column2,
                                        '1','C'
                                        'C')
                               ),
                   'E'),
       NULL)



CASE WHEN table2_column1 = '1' Then
     CASE WHEN table1_column = 'auto' THEN
               CASE WHEN table2_column2 = '1' THEN
                         CASE WHEN table2_column3 = '1' THEN
                              'A'
                              Else
                              'B'
                         END
                    ELSE
                         CASE WHEN table2_column2 = '1' THEN
                              'C'
                              Else
                              'D'
                         END
                    END
               END
          ELSE
               'E'
     END
     ELSE
          NULL
 END
```

Comment: Thanks! 2 questions: 1. where is 'RESULT E' 2. Why NULL?

Comment: edited for 'E'.. last value.. "[only if table2_column1= '1'] " .. if not NULL finally.( for completing, I assumed)

Comment: and if there is also: table2_column1 = '0' (which i wish to put '- - -'?

Comment: Before `ELSE NULL`, just add `WHEN table2_column1 = '0' THEN '---'`

Comment: Thanks! 1. table2_column1='0' isn't acceptable within the case (syntax error some how) 2. else 'E' producing (null) so i put only else 'NULL' (and not else 'E') and  then in the top select i put CASE
    WHEN table2_column1= '0'
    THEN '- - -'
    ELSE NVL (NULL, 'Manual')

Comment: Accept this as answer if it helped you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN table2.column1 <> '1'    OR table2.column1 IS NULL THEN NULL
     WHEN table1.column  <> 'auto' OR table1.column  IS NULL THEN 'E'
     WHEN table2.column2 = '1'    AND table2.column3 = '1'   THEN 'A'
     WHEN table2.column2 = '1'                               THEN 'B'
     WHEN table2.column2 = '1'                               THEN 'C'
                                                             ELSE 'D'
     END
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
CASE WHEN table2.column1 <> '1'    OR table2.column1 IS NULL THEN NULL
     WHEN table1.column  <> 'auto' OR table1.column  IS NULL THEN 'E'
     WHEN table2.column2 = '1'    AND table2.column3 = '1'   THEN 'A'
     WHEN table2.column2 = '1'                               THEN 'B'
                                                             ELSE 'D'
     END
```

(Since `C` can never be reached.)

Comment: why c can never reached?

Comment: If `table2.coloumn2 = '1'` then you will get result `A` or `B` (depending on the value of `table2.column3`) and you will only reach the condition to test for `C` or `D` when `table2.column2 <> '1'` and so `C` will never be reached. You can see this from my top answer where the conditions for `B` and `C` are identical and the earlier result (`B`) will be given in preference to `C`.